# How to use format specifiers to set field width of a string?

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting, format-specifiers

```
printf("%5s\n", "#");
```

gives:

```
    #
```

Is their a way to set field width of this string using an integer format specifier?

Something like this,

```
printf("%%ds\n", 5, "#");
```

Comment: First of all please don't tag multiple languages, only tag the one you're programming in. Secondly, any decent [`printf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) (and any good book) should have the information you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [printf manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

> Instead of a decimal digit string one may write "*" or "*m$" (for some decimal integer m) to specify that the field width is given in the next argument, or in the m-th argument, respectively, which must be of type int.

So in your example it would be:

```
printf("%*s\n", 5, "#");
```